# Creating a bash alias that ends in single quotation

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, alias

I have a command line string:

```
ls | sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g' | tr '\n' ' '
```

which outputs file names in the current folder, in a single line, surrounded by quotations.

I attempted to add this to my **.bash_profile** as an alias, however I think the single quotes are causing an issue and I can't get it to work.

I tried this with no luck:

```
alias='ls | sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g' | tr '\n' ' ''
```

How would one go about creating an alias for the above?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help with this noob question and I appreciate your time :)

Cheers,

Stephen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

work here with  using \"

```
alias X="ls | sed -e 's/^/\"/g' -e 's/$/\"/g' | tr '\n' ' '"
```

Comment: @StephenJPereira If you problem was resolved, you should accept an answer to close the question.

Answer (score 2):

Enquote the whole command in double quotes and escape the double quotes inside the command with a backslash:

```
alias a="ls | sed -e 's/^/\"/g' -e 's/$/\"/g' | tr '\n' ' '"
```

or use a function

```
a() {
    ls | sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g' | tr '\n' ' '
}
```

By the way: Parsing `ls` is a bad practice. It would be safer and easier to use globs and `printf`:

```
printf '"%s" ' *
```

or, if you want to *properly* quote for using the arguments inside `eval` or something similar

```
printf '%q ' *
```

Answer (score 0):

The alias should enclose the command line into `'` AND each already existing `'` should be escaped with `'\''`

Give a try to this:

```
alias lsquoted='ls | sed -e '\''s/^/"/g'\'' -e '\''s/$/"/g'\'' | tr '\''\n'\'' '\'' '\'''
```